# Interfacing SD card with STM32F44

Tags: stm32, spi, sd, stm32cubemx, sdio

I'm using STM32F44VET6 controller(using cubemx code configurator), I need to interface a 64GB SD card,and this controller has SDIO pheripheral also

But I'm confused how to choose interface type SPI or SDIO because memory size is high (64GB)

Please suggest  me which interface i have to use to get better speed and accuracy to  read and write?

Comment: sdio is faster but requires more signals

Comment: A flash based MCU is a bit of an odd choice for dealing with such a larger storage volume if you want speed; what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: we are developing control board for 3LCD projector ,SD  card is used to store videos,images and files

Comment: @aryan and what's going to decode that video?

Answer (score 1):

SPI has much less bandwidth so use the STM32 SDIO peripheral to provide faster transfer rates.